# Access ubuntu one files without downloading them

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

As I said in the title, I am searching for a way to check files on my Ubuntu One account without having to download them all, just to see what my folders contain.

Also, is there a feature that allows creating public links to some files in order to share them ? ( by giving a URL )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in to the [Ubuntu One website](https://one.ubuntu.com/) and see what folders and files you have there. You can also make them public and copy a link to share as well.

The easiest way to see your Ubuntu One data online is to launch the Ubuntu One application, then click on 'Go to the web for public and private sharing options'

The easiest way to publish and copy web links is from right within Nautilus, the default file browser. Right-click and choose 'Ubuntu One/Publish', then do it again and choose 'Copy web link'.

[image: U1 app screenshot]

[image: Nautilus right-click U1 Publishing]